# ObjectiveC Copying object from one NSMutableArray to another "invalid lvalue assignment"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, oop, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to make an object in one array equal to another. If I set each property individually, it works fine, but I want to set one object equal to antoher without writing a function to run through each property.

```
-(void)DrawCard: (int) wp{
[self GetNc :(wp)];
if (nc > 0){    
    ((card*) [[Hands objectAtIndex:wp] objectAtIndex:nc]) = ((card*) [[Draws objectAtIndex:wp] objectAtIndex:0])
}
```

}

(wp stands for which player. All GetNc does it set the integer nc (for new card), by finding the highest index of a card object currently being used in Hands).

That won't compile, but setting an individual property does:

```
    ((card*) [[Hands objectAtIndex:wp] objectAtIndex:nc]).suit = ((card*) [[Draws objectAtIndex:wp] objectAtIndex:0]).suit;
```

And trying without casting gives invalid l-value error as well ie:

```
        [[Hands objectAtIndex:wp] objectAtIndex:nc] = [[Draws objectAtIndex:wp] objectAtIndex:0];
```

(Is it ever possible to set an array object without casting?)

I appreciate your time to read and respond. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This will set that index of the array to point to the same object. I hope you understand that this does not copy the object.

```
[[Hands objectAtIndex:wp] replaceObjectAtIndex:nc withObject:[[Draws objectAtIndex:wp] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: So if the object in Draws changes, both Hands and Draws will return the new Draws value? Thanks.. how can I copy the object so I can adjust them independently?

Comment: If the object supports copying, then you can use the "copy" method to copy it.

Comment: Can you give an example? The objects in question are a card class I wrote. How do I make them support copying?

Comment: Are you sure you need to copy it? (If your card objects themselves are immutable then you don't need to copy it.) Anyway, to support copying, you implement the "copyWithZone:" method. Here is one that will perform shallow copying:
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return NSCopyObject(self, 0, zone);
}